# Get application to wait until Variables are updated

Tags: c#, oauth

I am working with OAuth at the moment. The problem with the current code is it doesn't wait until the user allows the application on the site and gets the proper key and secret. I was using a threading type wait but, sometimes it not long enough...some users are slower then others. I have attached a snippet of my code. What I would like to know is where to insert a while statement, or should I even use that ?

```
public OAuthToken GetRequestToken(Uri baseUri, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
{
    var uri = new Uri(baseUri, "oauth/request_token");
    uri = SignRequest(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var queryString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var parts = queryString.Split('&');
    var token = parts[1].Substring(parts[1].IndexOf('=') + 1);
    var secret = parts[0].Substring(parts[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);
    return new OAuthToken(token, secret);
}
```

Comment: What OAuth library are you using?

Comment: Can you please specify why you need to wait? What kind of application is this? Web, Desktop? There are many different approaches you can follow depending on the type of application

Comment: @klugerama As far as i can see i believe it is Dropbox REST API

Comment: @Jim where does it say it is a Dropbox REST API?

Comment: @Leo Nowhere, i'm just guessing [DropBoxPart5 Oauth](https://github.com/1989gaurav/monsterdrive/blob/master/DropboxPart5/OAuth/OAuth.cs) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should switch over to the newer **System.Net.Http** and **System.Net.Http.WebRequest** libraries that come with .NET now. These all use the new async programming stuff that is available with .NET 4.5.

You can call a request (returning you a task object that you can wait on) and automatically pause the thread for the response. The UI won't respond, as normal. That is probably the easiest thing to do if you don't understand how the new async and await keywords work. For more information on them, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Here is your code doing things with the new libraries:

```
using System.Net.Http;

public OAuthToken GetRequestToken(Uri baseUri, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
{
    var uri = new Uri(baseUri, "oauth/request_token");
    uri = SignRequest(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), uri);
    var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    // Use the http client to send the request to the server.
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask = client.SendAsync(message);

    // The responseTask object is like a wrapper for the other task thread.
    // We can tell this task object that we want to pause our current thread
    // and wait for the client.SendAsync call to finish.
    responseTask.Wait();

    // - Once that thread finishes, and the code continues on, we need to 
    //   tell it to read out the response data from the backing objects. 
    // - The responseTask.Result property represents the object the async task 
    //   was wrapping, we want to pull it out, then use it and get the content 
    //   (body of the response) back. 
    // - Getting the response actually creates another async task (the 
    //   .ReadAsStringAsync() call) but by accessing the .Result
    //   property, it is as if we called .ReadAsStringAsync().Wait(); Except that
    //   by using Result directly, we not only call Wait() but we get the resulting, 
    //   wrapped object back. Hope that didn't confuse you much :)
    var queryString = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // And all your other normal code continues.
    var parts = queryString.Split('&');
    var token = parts[1].Substring(parts[1].IndexOf('=') + 1);
    var secret = parts[0].Substring(parts[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);
    return new OAuthToken(token, secret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Not use a modal pop up and then call the authentication class on the submit button